# Using authorized_keys with git

Tags: ssh, git

I have transfered my ssh key from my root to my user account by `ssh-copy-id` command

so now I have these files in my .ssh folder

```
user@user-php:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys  config  id_rsa  id_rsa.pub  known_hosts
```

Now when I want to clone a project and actually the public key is in authorized_keys file it gives me error

```
user@user-php:/var/www/ts$ git clone git@xxxx.beanstalkapp.com:/xxxx.git
Cloning into 'xxxx'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

it is not pick up public key form authorized_keys

now why it not picking up the public key and is there any way i can tell git which public key to use.

EDIT: 
i have also try one more thing i have copyied all the keys from root/.ssh folder to user/.ssh but it still gives `Permission denied (publickey).` error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `id_rsa.pub` contents to the `authorized_keys` file depending on the version of OpenSSH that's installed on the server.

If `authorized_keys` doesn't exist, create it.

Also, make sure that you are copying the public key correctly. What I would do, transfer my `id_rsa.pub` to the server via SFTP, then on the server (via SSH if possible) run:

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry after some search i found out that to push and pull form git you need privte key for that public key which is kept on the server.
so i copied the private the to the `.ssh` folder and then added it to `ssh-agent` with

`ssh-add` command and then i was easily pull and push now